# What does "The information on this page is out dated" mean when updating apps in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes

When ever I try to download updates of my iApps in iTunes I get a dialog that says "The information on this page is out dated".

If I hit "Check for updates" again all is well.

Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this post](http://tech.kateva.org/2010/07/itunes-92-app-update-bug-information-on.html) can help you.

The most interessant part is last sentence saying :

- ***Update 7/25/10:** Fixed in an iTunes update.*

What version of iTunes are you running ?

Comment: Your Google Foo is better than mine :)
9.2.1 so I guess it's not fixed.

Comment: It appears this suggestion on the link you posted works..


After you get the "this page is outdated" error, click on your email address in the upper right corner, to access your iTunes account. It will prompt you for your password. Once you're on your account page, click Done, and you should be back at the "My App Updates" page. Now, updating all of your apps should work.

Comment: Nope, didn't work.